# Insert Elements to an ArrayList like intervals java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, arraylist

First example: I have ranges

```
[10, 30] [80, 100] [150, 200]
```

I have to insert for example `[90, 120]`. After, insertion, the resulting ranges will be:

```
[10, 30] [80, 120] [150, 200]
```

This happens because the range `[100, 120]` was not in the original range, so 100 gets increased to 120, but 90 will not be added because is in the range of 80 to 120.

Similarly, if I were to add `[50, 90]` to the original range, the resulting range would be

```
[10, 30] [50, 100] [150, 200]
```

This time, the lower bound gets reduced to 50, widening the range on the lower side, but the 90 is ignored because it is already in the range `[80, 100]`. I am attempting to make a class to represent this problem.

Currently, I take the start numbers into ArrayListStart `[10, 80, 150]` and the end numbers into ArrayListEnd `[30, 100, 200]` and I loop through them. I compare if it is smaller of the smallest number etc.

However, I cannot seem to get this method to work. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe someone else understands your question better, but it isn't very clear to me what you're trying to do. Do you have an example of some code you've tried?

Comment: @Trobbins I think it's pretty clear what he wants to do... think of it as a number line, and he's union-ing a range of numbers.

Comment: It's clearer now, after the edit. :)

Comment: @mbomb007 what would happen if he were to add `[40, 110]` then? Would it increase both or one?

Comment: The output would be `[10, 30] [40, 110] [150, 200]`, and if you then add `[100, 160]`, it would be `[10, 30] [40, 200]`.

Comment: @mbomb007 you understood it correctly. and if I want to add [120, 130], nothing changes. If I want to add [1, 220] the output is [220]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have something like this:

```
private Integer[] minArray = new Integer[]{10,80,150};
private Integer[] maxArray = new Integer[]{30,100,200};
```

So what you are looking for is something like this:

```
private void changeRange(int min, int max) {
    boolean found = false;
    int position=0;
    while(position<minArray.length && !found) {
        if(min>minArray[position] && min<maxArray[position]) {
            found = true;
            if(max>maxArray[position]) {
                maxArray[position] = max;
            }
        } else if(max>minArray[position] && max<maxArray[position]) {
            found = true;
            if(min<minArray[position]) {
                minArray[position] = min;
            }
        } else {
            position++;
        }
    }
}
```

So if your `min` is between a value in `minArray` and `maxArray`, change the value in maxArray for `max` (and `min` in case `max` is between `minArray` and `maxArray`).

You don't state what happens if the values are not in one of your ranges, so I have assumed nothing. Else, I'm sure you can figure out from here.

Comment: Can you tell me if this code will help me if for example I have [10, 50] [100 200] and I insert [20 150], then the result should be [10 200]

Comment: No, it will require some changes. That case was not in your original specs and adds extra complexity like eliminating ranges.

Comment: Yes, I have solved it with deleting the ranges and add new range with the smallest and biggest from the two existing ranges. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Guava [Range](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html) class and the implementations of the  [RangeSet](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/RangeSet.html)  interface.

> Implementations that choose to support the add(Range) operation are required to ignore empty ranges and coalesce connected ranges.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Range { int left, right; }

ArrayList<Range> list;

boolean intersects(Range r1, Range r2) { /* tests if 2 ranges intersect */ };
Range join (Range r1, Range r2) { /* joins two ranges */ }

void add(Range r) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (intersects(list.get(i), r)) {
            list.set(i, join(list.get(i), r));
            while (i + 1 < list.size() && intersects(list.get(i), list.get(i+1)) {
                Range rtemp = list.remove(i+1);
                list.set(i, join(list.get(i), rtemp));
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    if (i == list.size()) {
        list.add(r);
    }
}
```

1. Test from smallest to largest range, if none intersect, add to the end
2. If any existing range intersects, merge it with the new range.
3. Then test whether the merged range now intersects with the next existing range in the list, if so, merge it. Repeat 3 until the new range does not intersect the next range.

Comment: Thank you, this is great, I have never used it Range class and it gives lots of possibilities.

Comment: If I have ranges [10, 50] [70, 100] [150, 200] etc.
I have to insert for example 1.[20, 170] 2.[5, 170] 3.[20, 220] 4.[1, 230]
1. result should be: [10, 200], all instances that are in the range of this values should be deleted 2.result should be: [5, 200] , all instances that are in the range of this values should be deleted 3.result should be: [10, 220], all instances that are in the range of this values should be deleted 4.result should be: [1, 230], all instances that are in the range of this values should be deleted. What are the conditions then?